# strpos() doesn't work?

Tags: php, filesystems

i'm toying around with a php filesystem:

my php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Database Editor</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.comment {
    color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function interpret() {
    for ($count=1;!empty($fileline[$count]);$count++) {
        if (strpos($fileline[$count],"//")===0) {
            $fileline[$count]="<div class=\"comment\">".$fileline[$count]."</div>";
        }
    }
}
$filepath = "data.bdf";
//in bdf files, each line starts with ` and commented lines begin with `//
$filesize = @filesize($filepath);
if (!empty($filesize)) {
echo "File being opened contains ".$filesize." bytes of data. Opening file...<br />";
}
else {
    echo "Error in determining file size. ";
}
$handle = @fopen($filepath, "r") or die("File could not be opened");
echo "File Opened!<br />";
$filedata = fread($handle, $filesize+1) or die("File could not be read");
echo "File Read!<br /><br />Data in file:<br /><br />";
$fileline = explode("`",$filedata);
interpret();
for ($count=1;!empty($fileline[$count]);$count++) {
    echo $count.": ".$fileline[$count]."<br />";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the data.bdf file:
yes, i made my own filetype just for fun... :)

```
`//This is a comment
`This is not a comment
```

as you can probably tell, i'm reading the bdf file and trying to make all comments (lines that begin with // after the ` is removed) green when they are displayed on screen. this is not happening, but why? i think it's a problem here:

```
$fileline[$count]="<div class=\"comment\">".$fileline[$count]."</div>";
```

the html output is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Database Editor</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.comment {
    color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
File being opened contains 44 bytes of data. Opening file...<br />File Opened!<br />File Read!<br /><br />Data in file:<br /><br />1: //This is a comment
<br />2: This is not a comment<br /></body>
</html>
```

thank you so much for helping in advance

Comment: edit is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6376080/revisions  he removed the css tag.

Comment: 1) http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php - You need to pass your $fileline information to the function interpret(). Also, 2) Consider using a foreach loop instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `interpret()` references `$fileline`, which is a global variable, but does not use the `global` keyword.

Instead, pass `$fileline` to `interpret()` as an argument:

```
// Argument reference &$fileline
function interpret(&$fileline) {
  for ($count=1;!empty($fileline[$count]);$count++) {
    if (strpos($fileline[$count],"//")===0) {
        $fileline[$count]="<div class=\"comment\">".$fileline[$count]."</div>";
    }
  }
}

// Later, your function call...
$fileline = explode("`",$filedata);
interpret($fileline);
```

Note that above `interpret()` receives its argument by reference.  I'm not crazy about this, and you could also `return $fileline` at the end of the function and assign it with the call:

```
function interpret($fileline) {
  for ($count=1;!empty($fileline[$count]);$count++) {
    if (strpos($fileline[$count],"//")===0) {
        $fileline[$count]="<div class=\"comment\">".$fileline[$count]."</div>";
    }
  }
  // Return the argument instead
  return $fileline;
}

// Later, your function call...
$fileline = explode("`",$filedata);
$fileline = interpret($fileline);
```

Comment: @Ben7005 Yes, as I put in my later edit.  Redefine your function to require the `$fileline` argument and call it as you guessed.

Comment: @Michael Actually, you need to pass the variable as a reference: `function interpret(&$fileline) {`; otherwise, the actual `$fileline` outside of the function is unchanged when you call the function.

Comment: @Michael: Either you forgot 'pass by reference' or the 'return' statement.

Comment: @Ben7005 It doesn't work even after you've redefined your function as above?

Comment: @Ben7005 @Floern Added a `return` example as well, since its clearer than the pass by reference example.

Comment: thanks. if you want to check it out: http://www.webscaninc.com/trucheckupdates/mySQL-test/file_write.php

Comment: @Michael: Your example is using `return` and pass-by-ref at the same time. ;-)

Comment: @Floern Ugh. That's why we're not supposed to practice copy/paste programming, right?